# Can I use JSTL 1.1 / JSP 2.0 with Servlet 2.5?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

Can I use JSTL 1.1, JSP 2.0 with Servlet 2.5? I'm facing some problems like "value does not support runtime expressions" and I'm not sure about what's going on. If I change JSTL version to 1.2, everything works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: buddy, i need something concrete to send to my client but it's kinda hard to find it inside the documentation. Do you know if this table is safe http://dev-answers.blogspot.com.br/2006/12/according-to-tld-or-attribute.html#specs? The table says "Servlet 2.5 > JSTL 1.2 and JSP 2.1"

Comment: So i can use that way.,.tybm